# как при загрузке слайдера показывать разные изображения

Tags: jquery, slick.js

как при загрузке слайдера(каждый раз когда обновляем страницу, первые фотографии должны быть разными) показывать разные изображения, я использую slick.js:
js:

```
jQuery('.slick_main').slick({
            infinite: true,
            speed: 3000,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 7000,
            arrows: false,
            pauseOnFocus: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand'
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужен initialSlide в который нужно положить значение от 0 до slides.length - 1.

Функцию рандомизатор нагло стырил с learn javascript.

```
var slider = jQuery('.slick_main');

var slides = slider.find('.slick-slide')

function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
    rand = Math.floor(rand);
    return rand;
}

slider.slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 3000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    arrows: false,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    initialSlide: randomInteger(0, slides.length - 1)
});
```

Не проверял, но работать должно.